# Include in where clause if the value is not null

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I just return values based on inputted parameters, if the item description is null, I don't want to include that in the where clause.

Like item description, all other cases were same.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[WP_GetItems] 
    @IsActive     bit,
    @OrderMode    bit,
    @OrderBy      varchar(75),
    @Description  varchar(250),
    @DateFrom     datetime,
    @DateTo       datetime,
    @PriceFrom    float,
    @PriceTo      float
as
Begin 
    Select ItemID, ItemPartNumber, ItemDescription, CreatedDate, InitialPrice from Items where IsActive = @IsActive
    CASE
        WHEN @Description IS NOT NULL THEN AND ItemDescription LIKE '%' + @Description + '%' 
        WHEN @PriceFrom IS NOT NULL THEN AND InitialPrice >= @Price
        WHEN @PriceTo IS NOT NULL THEN AND InitialPrice <= @Price
    END 
    order by
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='ItemDescription' AND @OrderMode = 0 THEN ItemDescription END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='ItemDescription' AND @OrderMode = 1 THEN ItemDescription END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='ItemPartNumber' AND @OrderMode = 0 THEN ItemPartNumber END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='ItemPartNumber' AND @OrderMode = 1 THEN ItemPartNumber END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='CreatedDate' AND @OrderMode = 0 THEN CreatedDate END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='CreatedDate' AND @OrderMode = 1 THEN CreatedDate END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='InitialPrice' AND @OrderMode = 0 THEN InitialPrice END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='InitialPrice' AND @OrderMode = 1 THEN InitialPrice END DESC
End
```

But executing this query I got an error. `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.`

Comment: That's because you can't use a CASE statement like that. You need to use Dynamic SQL and work out your logic before you concatenate the where clause.

Comment: Actually, you don't need a case statement at all. Just do `where (@Description is null or ItemDescription = @Description) and (@PriceFrom is null or Price >= @PriceFrom)` etc. Also, as a side-note, note that `case` can only ever have one return value - so even if this did work (it can't), it would not allow you to search by more than one field at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the AND part inside your CASE.
Try this:

```
WHERE IsActive = @IsActive
AND ItemDescription LIKE CASE WHEN @Description IS NOT NULL THEN '%' + @Description + '%' END
AND InitialPrice >= CASE WHEN @PriceFrom IS NOT NULL THEN @PriceFrom ELSE InitialPrice END
AND InitialPrice <= CASE WHEN @PriceTo IS NOT NULL THEN @PriceTo ELSE InitialPrice END
```

Another option, as suggested by [Louaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3032289/luaan) in the comments, is to do this:

```
AND (@Description IS NULL OR ItemDescription LIKE '%'+ @Description +'%')
AND (@PriceFrom IS NULL OR InitialPrice >= @PriceFrom)
AND (@PriceTo IS NULL OR InitialPrice <= @PriceTo)
```

This option is better since there is no need for the sql server to test the actual data if the variable is null.

**Note #1** If either one of the columns is nullable you will need to decide how to treat null values, since `NULL = NULL` always return false.

**Note #2** You might want to include a recompile hint with this stored procedure to improve performance. [read this article to find out why](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/).

Comment: This would change the logical flow of the query wouldn't it? Does he want to search on all three?

Comment: If description is not null, search for description, if price is not null, include price in the where clause. This's my wish,.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include Luaan's suggestion. Both styles will get the same result. but I do believe that the second one is better.